# Using map to filter and return a new object in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code:

```
      allDesignDocs.rows.forEach((row: any) => {
        if (!designDocsName.includes(row.id.replace("_design/", ""))) {
          toBeRemoved = [{ _id: row.id, _rev: row.value.rev, "_deleted": true }, ...toBeRemoved];
        }

      });
```

which works fine. However I would like to use an in place update approach. So I chose map rather than foreach:

```
  var test = allDesignDocs.rows.map((row: any) => {
    if (!designDocsName.includes(row.id.replace("_design/", ""))) {
      return { _id: row.id, _rev: row.value.rev, "_deleted": true };
    }

  });
```

So the above returns arrays including undefined when the condition is not happy. I just want the array to contains values returned from inside if and ignore all undefined. I know I can loop trhough the result and clean it but that is not a clean way. Is there any es6 function which can provide the above functionality?

Comment: `.map` will do a 1:1 transformation of the array. If you want to return only *some* of the items, you need `.filter`

Comment: @VLAZ Yes but using filter will return the exact row fed to it however I have a transformation and I return a custom object: { _id: row.id, _rev: row.value.rev, "_deleted": true };

Comment: `.filter().map()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) after [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to filter `undefined` values.

```
var test = allDesignDocs.rows.map((row: any) => {
   if (!designDocsName.includes(row.id.replace("_design/", ""))) {
     return { _id: row.id, _rev: row.value.rev, "_deleted": true };
   }
 }).filter(item => item !== undefined); // Can also use filter(item => item);
```

Or use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
var test = allDesignDocs.rows.reduce((acc, row: any) => {
  if (!designDocsName.includes(row.id.replace("_design/", ""))) {
    acc.push({ _id: row.id, _rev: row.value.rev, "_deleted": true });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce`

For instance:

```
[1,2,3,4].reduce((acc,n)=>{
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        acc.push(n*4)
    }
    return acc;
},[])
```

Which would produce a list of even numbers * 4, alternatively combine `.filter` and `.map`.

Comment: Yes but using filter will return the exact row fed to it however I have a transformation and I return a custom object: { _id: row.id, _rev: row.value.rev, "_deleted": true };